# is mann whitney an alternative to t-test?

Tags: t-test, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

can i compare both of them ?
As i may change the sample size , variance and also skew the distribution.

However,some researcher claimed that comparing both of them couldnt make sense as it is just like comparing apple with peach.

So ,it make me stuck.
As i am referring this paper actually "should we always choose a nonparametric test when comparing two apparently nonnormal distribution?" by Skovlund and Fenstad.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly compare a t-test with the Mann Whitney U test.  You can use the Mann Whitney test as an alternative to a t-test when the assumptions of a t-test cannot be met.  The Mann Whitney U test is a nonparametric test that requires weaker assumptions, so it is often used in place of the t-test.  However, as it is a non-parametric test it is also less powerful.

Comment: Therefore, is the shift of location the additional assumptions of mann whitney is valid? to test the equality of median or even mean.

Comment: ** in this assumptions ,it has the same shape of distribution.

Comment: *less powerful* if the assumptions of the t-test is not met!

Comment: I like the first sentence in the answer, but not the rest .  The two tests test different hypotheses, and so are not alternatives to each other.  The *t* test compares means and Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney compares stochastic dominance...  The first thing is to decide what hypothesis you want to test.

Comment: @SalMangiafico, that's a fair point.  I guess I should have been more clearer and indicated that one often changes the hypothesis to be tested if the assumptions of a $t$-test cannot be met, in this way, the U test is frequently choosen to replace the $t$-test.

Comment: Yes, I know.  I guess I was being so stark just to emphasize the difference in the hypotheses.  I wish we would teach students to think about these tests as testing different hypotheses, rather than a t-test being the default and a nonparametric test being an alternative.  (And there are other options for example if we want to think about medians or other quantiles, and so on). I apologize for my starkness.  +1 for the answer.

Comment: Oh, I didn't think you were being stark at all.  I think the comment was a good one.  I agree too with your sentiments regarding the teaching of this material too.